# Round a range in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have df_surf_dist=

```
                 index  surface_relle_bati
0      (8.718, 27.733]                 442
1     (27.733, 46.467]                1485
2       (46.467, 65.2]                1296
3       (65.2, 83.933]                 927
4    (83.933, 102.667]                 288
5     (102.667, 121.4]                  81
6     (121.4, 140.133]                  22
7   (140.133, 158.867]                   8
8     (158.867, 177.6]                  10
9     (177.6, 196.333]                   1
10  (196.333, 215.067]                   1
11    (215.067, 233.8]                   1
12    (233.8, 252.533]                   0
13  (252.533, 271.267]                   0
14    (271.267, 290.0]                   1
```

I want to round the range in order to plot it and make the scale look nice.

I tried `df_surf_dist.index.round(decimals=-1)`

but I got `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'round'`

I also tried `df_surf_dist.index = df_surf_dist.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.round(1))`

but I got `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'round'`

Comment: can you provide the constructor for the input?

Comment: The question would be how did you get the range index in the first place? You should probably round the numbers there.

Comment: Based on another df :
`df_surf_dist=df_w_o['surface_relle_bati'].value_counts(bins=15, sort=False)`

`df_surf_dist = df_surf_dist.reset_index(name='surface_relle_bati')`

Comment: I bet if you changed your column name from `index` to something else, you will get less trouble. Try that and still see if your problem persists. `df.index` is handling the *index* of your dataframe and not your column. or use `df['index']`

Comment: You can try switching to `pd.cut` using the `precision=1` argument, but because of floats you'll still get stuff like `(-3.3000000000000003, -1.3]` for your lowest bins

Comment: can you provide the output of `df_surf_dist.to_dict()`?

Comment: Got the same errors with a new name

Comment: @mozway - `pd.read_clipboard()` will handle the OP's dataframe

Comment: @MattR not with the correct type

Comment: @mozway 
`{'index': {0: Interval(8.718, 27.733, closed='right'), 1: Interval(27.733, 46.467, closed='right'), 2: Interval(46.467, 65.2, closed='right'), etc}, 'surface_relle_bati': {0: 442, 1: 1485, 2: 1296, 3: 927, 4: 288, 5: 81, 6: 22, 7: 8, 8: 10, 9: 1, 10: 1, 11: 1, 12: 0, 13: 0, 14: 1}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom function to recreate the intervals:

```
def round_interval(i, ndigits=2):
    return pd.Interval(round(i.left, ndigits), round(i.right, ndigits), i.closed)

df['range'].apply(round_interval, ndigits=1)
```

output:

```
0     (8.7, 27.7]
1    (27.7, 46.5]
2    (46.5, 65.2]
Name: range, dtype: interval
```

used input:

```
from pandas import Interval
d = {'range': {0: Interval(8.718, 27.733, closed='right'),
               1: Interval(27.733, 46.467, closed='right'),
               2: Interval(46.467, 65.2, closed='right')},
     'surface_relle_bati': {0: 442, 1: 1485, 2: 1296}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: It worked! 
Is it possible to use the same function to round another interval?
`                   range  surface_relle_bati`
`0     (24255.0, 74667.0]                 754`


I would like to get :
 `(25000.0, 75000.0]                 754`

Comment: Fixed with ndigits=-3, txs legend!